# Simple Html não retorna nada?

Tags: php, web-scraping

**Código:**

```
require_once("simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php");
html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://www.g1.globo.com/');
echo $html;
```

**Erros:**

> Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=10053
>   Uma conex�o estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_html_dom\simple_html_dom.php on line 1081
>
> Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 24 bytes failed with errno=10053
>   Uma conex�o estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_html_dom\simple_html_dom.php on line 1081
>
> Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 19 bytes failed with errno=10053
>   Uma conex�o estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_html_dom\simple_html_dom.php on line 1081
>
> Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=10053
>   Uma conex�o estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_html_dom\simple_html_dom.php on line 1081
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.g1.globo.com/): failed to open
>   stream: HTTP request failed! in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_html_dom\simple_html_dom.php on line 1081
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function innertext() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_html_dom\simple_html_dom.php on line 1688

Como poderia solucionar esse problema?

Observação: g1.globo.com é apenas um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se a opção **allow_url_fopen** e está ativo no seu servidor, esta configuração geralmente pode ser feita via php.ini.

Comment: Verifiquei e está sim, amigo.
"allow_url_fopen=On"

Comment: Esta classe **simple_html_dom** ela faz o que, você que a fez?